# pgr_pointsaspolygon returns a self intersecting polygon which does not cover underlying points

Tags: pgrouting

I am using pgrouting 2.0 library to create an alpha shape around my set of points.
It works nearly perfect but I have a case where pgr_pointsaspolygon returns a self intersecting polygon which does not really cover the underlying points in the table:

[image]

This is how i call the pgr_pointsaspolygon function :

```
SELECT 1 as a,* FROM  pgr_pointsaspolygon('SELECT id, ST_X(the_geom) AS x, ST_Y(the_geom) AS y FROM test')
```

Is there anyway i can correct the result?

---

A bug was report here: https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/issues/235

Comment: Seems like you should file a bug report.

Comment: I have opened an issue on github.

Answer (score 1):

I believe some point in your points' set must be the problem (the code is ok).

**1)** You may try to search it for errors using Topology Checker in QGIS:

[image]

**2)** Also, you may try another Topology checking as stated **[here](http://docs.pgrouting.org/dev/doc/src/tutorial/index.html)**, using `pgr_createTopology` and `pgr_analyzeGraph`:

[image]

As you can see, it is possible to have NULL ids besides NULL geometries.

If you intend to use the second error checking method, please, assure yourself you have already these columns in your points' table:

[image]

Only after this step, run this code at once:

```sql
SELECT pgr_createTopology('points',0.001,'the_geom','gid','source','target','true');
SELECT pgr_analyzeGraph('points', 0.001, 'the_geom','gid','source','target','true');
```

---

**EDIT**:

It seems I need to open an issue on github, also:

[image]

Comment: I checked test table with topology checker in QGIS with no errors. For the pgr_analyzeGraph part: pgr_pointsaspolygon function takes an sql which should return id, x and y coordinates of a set of points. As it doesnt take any parameter for the topology table, it does not know anything about the topology. So probably the problem isnt there.